# Add Marker on google map via onmapclick

Tags: java, android, android-studio

First thing to say: i'm a novice programmer...
i'm trying to modifying an open source i've found on github and i have this problem: adding markers don't work when i tap while debugging my app.

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    if (mMarker == null) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.title(latLng.toString())
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true);
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    } else {
        mMarker.setPosition(latLng);
        mMarker.setTitle(latLng.toString());
        mMarker.showInfoWindow();
    }
}
```

The public class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
```

Beside my if-else code, i tried many of the codes examples i've read here on stackoverflow and on google api docs, but still do nothing when i tap the phone screen.

Sorry for my english...

Comment: you sure you have `yourmapobject.setOnMapClickListener(this)` inside `onmapready`?

Comment: But onMapClick is outside the brackets of onMapReady.
I still need that code you wrote inside onMapReady?

Comment: put `Log.e(TAG, "map click");` in your `onMapClick()` method and check if it is logged when you tap your map

Comment: @Barns i did it but nothing happens

Comment: add code of whole activity it will help

Comment: I did it! @Pavneet_Singh code did the trick. It works even if onMapClick is outside the brackets

Answer (score 1):

As @Pavneet_Singh wrote, this did the trick:

Before:

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}
```

After:

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
}
```